Why does running Llama 3.1 70B model underutilises the GPU?
I have deployed Llama 3.1 70B and Llama 3.1 8B on my system and it works perfectly for the 8B model. When I tested it for 70B, it underutilized the GPU and took a lot of time to respond. Here are the system details:
CPU: Ryzen 7 3700x, RAM: 48g ddr4 2400, SSD: NVME m.2, GPU: RTX 3060 ti, Motherboard: B550 M:
sudo docker logs cybersage-lama
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.081Z level=INFO source=server.go:105 msg="system memory" total="47.0 GiB" free="45.8 GiB" free_swap="3.9 GiB"
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.082Z level=INFO source=memory.go:343 msg="offload to cuda" layers.requested=-1 layers.model=81 layers.offload=10 layers.split="" memory.available="[7.5 GiB]" memory.gpu_overhead="0 B" memory.required.full="44.0 GiB" memory.required.partial="7.2 GiB" memory.required.kv="640.0 MiB" memory.required.allocations="[7.2 GiB]" memory.weights.total="38.9 GiB" memory.weights.repeating="38.1 GiB" memory.weights.nonrepeating="822.0 MiB" memory.graph.full="324.0 MiB" memory.graph.partial="1.1 GiB"
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.085Z level=INFO source=server.go:380 msg="starting llama server" cmd="/usr/lib/ollama/runners/cuda_v12/ollama_llama_server --model /root/.ollama/models/blobs/sha256-de20d2cf2dc430b1717a8b07a9df029d651f3895dbffec4729a3902a6fe344c9 --ctx-size 2048 --batch-size 512 --n-gpu-layers 10 --threads 8 --parallel 1 --port 44611"
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.086Z level=INFO source=sched.go:449 msg="loaded runners" count=1
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.086Z level=INFO source=server.go:559 msg="waiting for llama runner to start responding"
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.087Z level=INFO source=server.go:593 msg="waiting for server to become available" status="llm server error"
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.150Z level=INFO source=runner.go:939 msg="starting go runner"
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.150Z level=INFO source=runner.go:940 msg=system info="AVX = 1 | AVX_VNNI = 0 | AVX2 = 0 | AVX512 = 0 | AVX512_VBMI = 0 | AVX512_VNNI = 0 | AVX512_BF16 = 0 | FMA = 0 | NEON = 0 | SVE = 0 | ARM_FMA = 0 | F16C = 0 | FP16_VA = 0 | RISCV_VECT = 0 | WASM_SIMD = 0 | BLAS = 1 | SSE3 = 1 | SSSE3 = 1 | VSX = 0 | MATMUL_INT8 = 0 | LLAMAFILE = 1 | cgo(gcc)" threads=8
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.150Z level=INFO source=.:0 msg="Server listening on 127.0.0.1:44611"
llama_model_loader: loaded meta data with 29 key-value pairs and 724 tensors from /root/.ollama/models/blobs/sha256-de20d2cf2dc430b1717a8b07a9df029d651f3895dbffec4729a3902a6fe344c9 (version GGUF V3 (latest))
llama_model_loader: Dumping metadata keys/values. Note: KV overrides do not apply in this output.
llama_model_loader: - kv   0:                       general.architecture str              = llama
llama_model_loader: - kv   1:                               general.type str              = model
llama_model_loader: - kv   2:                               general.name str              = Meta Llama 3.1 70B Instruct
llama_model_loader: - kv   3:                           general.finetune str              = Instruct
llama_model_loader: - kv   4:                           general.basename str              = Meta-Llama-3.1
llama_model_loader: - kv   5:                         general.size_label str              = 70B
llama_model_loader: - kv   6:                            general.license str              = llama3.1
llama_model_loader: - kv   7:                               general.tags arr[str,6]       = ["facebook", "meta", "pytorch", "llam...
llama_model_loader: - kv   8:                          general.languages arr[str,8]       = ["en", "de", "fr", "it", "pt", "hi", ...
llama_model_loader: - kv   9:                          llama.block_count u32              = 80
llama_model_loader: - kv  10:                       llama.context_length u32              = 131072
llama_model_loader: - kv  11:                     llama.embedding_length u32              = 8192
llama_model_loader: - kv  12:                  llama.feed_forward_length u32              = 28672
llama_model_loader: - kv  13:                 llama.attention.head_count u32              = 64
llama_model_loader: - kv  14:              llama.attention.head_count_kv u32              = 8
llama_model_loader: - kv  15:                       llama.rope.freq_base f32              = 500000.000000
llama_model_loader: - kv  16:     llama.attention.layer_norm_rms_epsilon f32              = 0.000010
llama_model_loader: - kv  17:                          general.file_type u32              = 15
llama_model_loader: - kv  18:                           llama.vocab_size u32              = 128256
llama_model_loader: - kv  19:                 llama.rope.dimension_count u32              = 128
llama_model_loader: - kv  20:                       tokenizer.ggml.model str              = gpt2
llama_model_loader: - kv  21:                         tokenizer.ggml.pre str              = llama-bpe
llama_model_loader: - kv  22:                      tokenizer.ggml.tokens arr[str,128256]  = ["!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", ...
llama_model_loader: - kv  23:                  tokenizer.ggml.token_type arr[i32,128256]  = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
time=2024-12-05T09:04:12.341Z level=INFO source=server.go:593 msg="waiting for server to become available" status="llm server loading model"
llama_model_loader: - kv  24:                      tokenizer.ggml.merges arr[str,280147]  = ["Ġ Ġ", "Ġ ĠĠĠ", "ĠĠ ĠĠ", "...
llama_model_loader: - kv  25:                tokenizer.ggml.bos_token_id u32              = 128000
llama_model_loader: - kv  26:                tokenizer.ggml.eos_token_id u32              = 128009
llama_model_loader: - kv  27:                    tokenizer.chat_template str              = {{- bos_token }}\n{%- if custom_tools ...
llama_model_loader: - kv  28:               general.quantization_version u32              = 2
llama_model_loader: - type  f32:  162 tensors
llama_model_loader: - type q4_K:  441 tensors
llama_model_loader: - type q5_K:   40 tensors
llama_model_loader: - type q6_K:   81 tensors
llm_load_vocab: special tokens cache size = 256
llm_load_vocab: token to piece cache size = 0.7999 MB
llm_load_print_meta: format           = GGUF V3 (latest)
llm_load_print_meta: arch             = llama
llm_load_print_meta: vocab type       = BPE
llm_load_print_meta: n_vocab          = 128256
llm_load_print_meta: n_merges         = 280147
llm_load_print_meta: vocab_only       = 0
llm_load_print_meta: n_ctx_train      = 131072
llm_load_print_meta: n_embd           = 8192
llm_load_print_meta: n_layer          = 80
llm_load_print_meta: n_head           = 64
llm_load_print_meta: n_head_kv        = 8
llm_load_print_meta: n_rot            = 128
llm_load_print_meta: n_swa            = 0
llm_load_print_meta: n_embd_head_k    = 128
llm_load_print_meta: n_embd_head_v    = 128
llm_load_print_meta: n_gqa            = 8
llm_load_print_meta: n_embd_k_gqa     = 1024
llm_load_print_meta: n_embd_v_gqa     = 1024
llm_load_print_meta: f_norm_eps       = 0.0e+00
llm_load_print_meta: f_norm_rms_eps   = 1.0e-05
llm_load_print_meta: f_clamp_kqv      = 0.0e+00
llm_load_print_meta: f_max_alibi_bias = 0.0e+00
llm_load_print_meta: f_logit_scale    = 0.0e+00
llm_load_print_meta: n_ff             = 28672
llm_load_print_meta: n_expert         = 0
llm_load_print_meta: n_expert_used    = 0
llm_load_print_meta: causal attn      = 1
llm_load_print_meta: pooling type     = 0
llm_load_print_meta: rope type        = 0
llm_load_print_meta: rope scaling     = linear
llm_load_print_meta: freq_base_train  = 500000.0
llm_load_print_meta: freq_scale_train = 1
llm_load_print_meta: n_ctx_orig_yarn  = 131072
llm_load_print_meta: rope_finetuned   = unknown
llm_load_print_meta: ssm_d_conv       = 0
llm_load_print_meta: ssm_d_inner      = 0
llm_load_print_meta: ssm_d_state      = 0
llm_load_print_meta: ssm_dt_rank      = 0
llm_load_print_meta: ssm_dt_b_c_rms   = 0
llm_load_print_meta: model type       = 70B
llm_load_print_meta: model ftype      = Q4_K - Medium
llm_load_print_meta: model params     = 70.55 B
llm_load_print_meta: model size       = 39.59 GiB (4.82 BPW) 
llm_load_print_meta: general.name     = Meta Llama 3.1 70B Instruct
llm_load_print_meta: BOS token        = 128000 '<|begin_of_text|>'
llm_load_print_meta: EOS token        = 128009 '<|eot_id|>'
llm_load_print_meta: LF token         = 128 'Ä'
llm_load_print_meta: EOT token        = 128009 '<|eot_id|>'
llm_load_print_meta: EOM token        = 128008 '<|eom_id|>'
llm_load_print_meta: EOG token        = 128008 '<|eom_id|>'
llm_load_print_meta: EOG token        = 128009 '<|eot_id|>'
llm_load_print_meta: max token length = 256
ggml_cuda_init: GGML_CUDA_FORCE_MMQ:    no
ggml_cuda_init: GGML_CUDA_FORCE_CUBLAS: no
ggml_cuda_init: found 1 CUDA devices:
  Device 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, compute capability 8.6, VMM: yes
llm_load_tensors: ggml ctx size =    0.68 MiB
llm_load_tensors: offloading 10 repeating layers to GPU
llm_load_tensors: offloaded 10/81 layers to GPU
llm_load_tensors:        CPU buffer size = 40543.11 MiB
llm_load_tensors:      CUDA0 buffer size =  5188.75 MiB
llama_new_context_with_model: n_ctx      = 2048
llama_new_context_with_model: n_batch    = 512
llama_new_context_with_model: n_ubatch   = 512
llama_new_context_with_model: flash_attn = 0
llama_new_context_with_model: freq_base  = 500000.0
llama_new_context_with_model: freq_scale = 1
llama_kv_cache_init:  CUDA_Host KV buffer size =   560.00 MiB
llama_kv_cache_init:      CUDA0 KV buffer size =    80.00 MiB
llama_new_context_with_model: KV self size  =  640.00 MiB, K (f16):  320.00 MiB, V (f16):  320.00 MiB
llama_new_context_with_model:  CUDA_Host  output buffer size =     0.52 MiB
llama_new_context_with_model:      CUDA0 compute buffer size =  1088.45 MiB
llama_new_context_with_model:  CUDA_Host compute buffer size =    20.01 MiB
llama_new_context_with_model: graph nodes  = 2566
llama_new_context_with_model: graph splits = 914
time=2024-12-05T09:04:19.620Z level=INFO source=server.go:598 msg="llama runner started in 7.53 seconds"

Here is the output of nvidia-smi when a request is sent to the model using 70B:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti     On  |   00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   57C    P0             74W /  225W |    6534MiB /   8192MiB |      5%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                     
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A   3129822      C   ...unners/cuda_v12/ollama_llama_server       6524MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Here is how I deployed Llama 3.1 on the machine:

Pull the LLaMA Docker Image: Pull the LLaMA Docker image (in this case, ollama/ollama):
sudo docker pull ollama/ollama

This test was successful.

Test GPU Access: You can test GPU access by running a CUDA base image to confirm that Docker recognizes your GPU:
sudo docker run --rm nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-base-ubuntu22.04 nvidia-smi


Run the LLaMA Container: Run the LLaMA container with GPU access, mapping the host port to the container’s port without additional environment variables:
sudo docker run -d --gpus all -p 11434:11434 --name cybersage-lama ollama/ollama



I am not sure why it is underutilizing the GPU and everything is going slow.

You need ~148GB of VRAM to run a 70B unquantised model (16FP). And ~ 48GB to run an INT4 quantised model.
You can see from the logs that 10 out of the 81 layers are in the GPU.
llm_load_tensors: offloading 10 repeating layers to GPU
llm_load_tensors: offloaded 10/81 layers to GPU

The other layers will run in the CPU, and thus the slowness and low GPU use.
I can see that the total model is using ~45GB of ram (5 in the GPU and 40 on the CPU), so I reckon you are running an INT4 quantised model). You can see some of this in the logs you shared
llm_load_tensors:        CPU buffer size = 40543.11 MiB
llm_load_tensors:      CUDA0 buffer size =  5188.75 MiB

To know the amount of memory required multiply the number of parameters by the size of weight.
16FP is 2 bytes so ~ 140GB. INT4 is 0.5 bytes = ~35GB. In practice one needs more than the bare minimum to run the model.

Thanks. Could you please share some reference where it mentions these things? I mean about the requirements for the VRAM of GPU?

I am not finding any clear indications of GPU requirements for these models on hugging face or Github.

I've updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Happened to me once, I think you'd need to improve the memory for the 70B model since it requires significantly more GPU memory than the 8B model.
FYI Your RTX 3060 Ti has only 8 GB of VRAM, and the log indicates that only 10 layers of the 70B model are offloaded to the GPU, hence the rest run on the CPU.. Your options are switching to a GPU with bigger RAM or using a smaller model.
